# Do I have to parse a JSON string and then traverse the resulting object or can I just traverse the string?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm learning Google Maps API; a call to its geolocation API returns a giant JSON string (sample: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=66+Fort+Washington+Avenue+New+Yor,NY&key=AIzaSyAGLzbjA0rEl5whQgiuZZdIGVzPZzLv9Kg). If I'm looking for a particular key/value pair out of that resulting set of data to use in my Java script application, is it better to convert that JSON string into an object (parse) and then traverse that object for that key/value pair, or is it Ok just to traverse the returned JSON string itself? What are the pros/cons of each?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the JSON will always result in easier to read code and is less sensitive to changes in the data that you are receiving. However, if you are looking at pure performance it depends on how unique the data is that you are searching for in the returned JSON string, and how many searches you are doing. If you (for instance) just wanted the lat/long location from the returned string you mentioned above then you could do this:

```
var index = string.search("location");
var index2 = string.substring(index).search(/-?\d/); // finds first number
lat = parseFloat(string.substring(index+index2));
var index3 = string.substring(index+index2).search("lng");
var index4 = string.substring(index+index2+index3).search(/-?\d/); // finds first number
lon = parseFloat(string.substring(index+index2+index3+index4));
```

Or, by parsing it you could do this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
lat = obj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat;
lon = obj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lon;
```

Clearly the parsed version is easier to read. However, I ran this 200000 times each, and found that the string search based approach was slightly more than 4 times faster than the JSON object parsing approach. There may have been other ways to optimize the search based approach but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON.parse` to turn your string into a JavaScript object before attempting to access its properties. You cannot *"traverse the returned JSON string itself"*:

```js
var json = '{ "property": "value" }'
// JSON strings cannot be traversed
console.log(typeof json) //=> "string"
console.log(json.property) //=> undefined


var object = JSON.parse(json)
// Objects can be traversed
console.log(typeof object) //=> "object"
console.log(object.property) //=> "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the api is returning json inside an string, you could parse it and just go throught the elements till you find what you need. Otherwise how would you traverse the string? From my point of view, that's something you shouldn't do.

Comment: Based on guides, it seems if you create a "JSON" string in Javascript, it's not really a "JSON string" until you stringify it; untill than it's just a Javascript object written via JSON syntax. I'm assuming that the JSON object returned by this API was actually stringified and thus needs to actually be parsed?

Comment: The issue here is that the response you're getting is a JSON, there is no string. If there response (but this is not the case) were a JSON embebed inside an string, you would need to parse it.